# Using classpath scanning to discover Spring Data Mongodb converters

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

If I declare the following in my Spring context file ([as described in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.core.html#mongo.custom-converters.xml)), my MongoMappingConverter is initialized with no custom converters:

```
<mongo:mapping-converter id="mappingConverter">
  <mongo:custom-converters base-package="com.company.mongo.converters.*" />
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

In contrast, if I explicitly reference the converters, they're initialized and used by the MongoMappingConverter.

```
<mongo:mapping-converter id="mappingConverter">
  <mongo:custom-converters>
    <mongo:converter>
      <bean class="com.company.mongo.converters.enums.CountryCodeWriteConverter"/>
    </mongo:converter>
    <mongo:converter>
      <bean class="com.company.mongo.converters.enums.CountryCodeReadConverter"/>
    </mongo:converter>
  </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

I've tried various different values of `base-package` (ending with "converters.enums", "converters.enums.*", "converters.**", "**.converters.enums"), all to no effect. Does anyone know how to make this work?

I'm using Spring Data Mongodb v1.4.2 with Spring v3.2.13. Upgrading to the latest release in the Spring Data Mongodb v1.5.x family would be relatively simple, but beyond that would require upgrading Spring to v4.x, which would not be a small task.

Comment: That should work. As it's a base package, simply using `com.company.mongo.converters` should be sufficient. Do you have a minimal sample that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @OliverGierke I'll try to extract something minimal. Right now, it's hopelessly entangled with a lot of other code. By the way, just to confirm, you're saying that `base-package="com.company.mongo.converters"` should discover Converters in the `enums` "sub-package"?

Comment: Yes. Make sure they're annotated with @Component though.

Comment: @OliverGierke that worked! Thanks! The doc that I link to at the beginning of the question doesn't mention the `@Component` requirement. That would definitely be an important detail to add. I'd submit a doc pull request, but I'm guessing you'd do a better job of explaining why it's needed. Could you please add an answer mentioning that and I'll accept it?

Comment: Feel free to create a ticket in our JIRA. Wouldn't mind a PR, either. Base package basically just uses arbitrary component scanning, that's why the annotation is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `Converter` implementations are annotated with `@Component`. The infrastructure uses arbitrary component scanning to find converters to apply.